# Build category in the properties of Visual Studio 2017 missing

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm currently following a tutorial on how to create conditional compilation symbols on Visual Studio, and it looks like the reason I can't figure out how to do that is because My properties window is different from what I can seem to find online.

Here is an image taken from the tutorial, showing how to create those symbols:

[image: Desired Properties window]

And here is what my properties list looks like:

[image: My Properties window]

I've been looking seemingly everywhere in options but can't find how to either turn on the build (and build events) buttons, or where to set up some conditional compilation symbols.

Would anyone know how to fix my issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I ended up finding an answer myself, so I'm going to post it here just in case others end up running into the same issue.

So, for an unknown reason (unknown to me at least), my conditional compilation symbols are under the "Compilation Constants" category.
It can be accessed using the following path:

***Project → Project Properties → Compile → Advanced Compile Options → Custom Constants*** (see image below for more information)

[image]